# Link one Portfolio Gallery URL to another by way of Custom Query in WP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, codex

I would like to link a Visual Portfolio Gallery to another gallery filter by way of querying particular custom post types. I have already tried custom queries in the lines of `post_type="post, cubeportfolio"` since I will be referencing all posts from the cubeportfolio gallery plugin with post type slug "cubeportfolio".

This method seems to work with other custom posts but not posts from the cubeportfolio gallery. The Portfolio Gallery i am trying to link is embedded in this page here http://tile.johnzuh.com/. Link to plugin website https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-portfolio/ for reference purposes.

I might just need some tips on how to query filters from another plugin in wordpress or simply just link the URL of the filters directly to the visual portfolio i am using so when user clicks on them it takes them directly to a particular category and its respective gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Cube Portfolio as it's a paid plugin, but I did download Visual Portfolio to check it out. Have you considered trying to filter things via the post category instead?

This way you wouldn't have to do any registering of custom post types in your functions.php file ([see here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)). You could add categories to your items and reference them using the code below.

```
is_category('Category A')
```

You could obviously use a combination of both post_type and is_category in your query to get the desired result.

Comment: will check it out.